# Variance decompostion for logistic regression using deviances?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, deviance, variance-decomposition

I have data on the proportion of methylated cytosines in a gene from 13 plant genotypes from replicate experiments at four sites. Each genotype is replicated at each site, so and I would like to quantify how much of the variation in methylation is due to genotype, to site and to the interaction between genotype and site.

If this were a trait with homogenous variance then I would do a classic partitioning of the sums of squares. Since I'm working with proportion data, I am instead fitting a binomial GLM, but then you get deviances instead of sums of squares. Here is an example in R:

```
> m <- glm(meth ~ genotype * site, data=cg, family=binomial)
> anova(m)
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: binomial, link: logit

Response: meth

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


                        Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev
NULL                                      179     1.8435
genotype                11  0.21179       168     1.6317
site                     3  0.02283       165     1.6089
genotype:site           33  0.55343       132     1.0555
```

**My question is**: is it valid to quantify variance explained by directly substituting the deviances for what would be sums of squares? 
Here is an example of what I mean:

```
> data.frame(
     var = c('genotype','site', 'genotype:site', "residual"),
     explained = c(0.21178648, 0.02282985, 0.55343393, 1.05547605)
)
> s$explained <- s$explained / sum(s$explained)
> s

genotype           0.115
site               0.012
genotype:site      0.300
Residual error     0.573
```

My interpretation would be that the genotype x site explains 30% of the variation, genotype 12% an site around 1%, which most variance going unexplained.

To be clear, I am not interesting in testing significance, only in quantifying which factors are explaining the variation. I feel this ought to be a simple problem, but I haven't been able to find a source with a straight answer, because almost all discussions I have found focus on testing, not quantifying. Any suggestions for sources on this would be very welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Let me mention two concerns. First, the analysis of deviance table is not uniquely determined by the fitted model. If you use `meth ~ site*genotype` instead the fitted model remains the same but the output analysis of deviance table is changed (because the table is sequential). Second, if the response variable `meth` is binary then the concept of partitioning the variance has no meaning. The variance of a binary random variable is completely determined by its mean.

Comment: `meth` is not binary - the underlying data are proportions, and there is variance among the proportions. This actually makes me think beta regression would be more appropriate.

Comment: The point about the order of the table is something I hadn't realised though, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: If `meth` is a proportion, then the analysis is wrong. You need to use the `weights` argument of `glm` to indicate the number of cases that the proportion was computed from. That would explain why the deviances are so strangely small.

Comment: Did you figure out an answer, @tellis? I'm working on a similar question

Comment: @canderson156, I concluded it was better to fit things as a random effect with something like lme4. For example: glmer(meth ~ ( 1| genotype) + (1|site)  + (1|genotype : site), data=cg, family=binomial)